# How to get column that has more than one record

Tags: sql

in SQL I have this currently:

```
Checklist Name | Version

Checklist A     1.1
Checklist A     2.1
Checklist B     1.1
Checklist C     1.1
Checklist C     2.1
Checklist C     3.1
```

I am trying to get only the records that have more than one version (so NOT checklist B). **This is my desired outcome:**

```
Checklist Name | Version

Checklist A     1.1
Checklist A     2.1
Checklist C     1.1
Checklist C     2.1
Checklist C     3.1
```

I am having trouble with this because I tried using a having clause and it is only letting me select the checklist name, so this would work

```
select checklistname
from checklisttable
group by checklistname
having count(version) > 1
```

The above would product this output:

```
Checklist A
Checklist C
```

But this (which is what I need cause I want to see the versions, DOESN'T work):

```
select checklistname, version
from checklisttable
group by checklistname, version
having count(version) > 1
```

This returns 0 records.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: You need to join your first query, as a subquery, back to the original table.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use your query as a derived table and join it back to the original table to get the rest of the fields:

```
select t1.*
from checklisttable t1
join (
  select checklistname
  from checklisttable
  group by checklistname
  having count(version) > 1
) t2 on t1.checklistname = t2.checklistname
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use window functions to do this:-

```
select * from
(
select
    Checklist_Name,
    Version,
    count(Checklist_Name) over(partition by Checklist_Name) c
from checklisttable
) data
where c > 1
```